# Inicializar una referencia a un objeto en el fichero .h

Tags: c++11

Tengo un problema, al ejecutar la siguiente inicialización de una una referencia a un objeto en el fichero.h. En principio no muestra el compilador ningun tipo de problema:

```
class Book{
public:

   Author author2=Author("julio","juio@somewhere.com", 'm');
   const Author &refAuthor=author2;
}
```

También probé:

```
class Book{
public:
    const Author &refAuthor=Author("julio","juio@somewhere.com", 'm');

}
```

Pero cuando lo lanzo en modo debug. Despues del llamar al método print()

```
   cppDummy.refAuthor.print();
```

Me muestra, lo que os adjunto en la imagen, es como si el objeto Author creado no se hubiera asignado y tuviera los atributos vacios.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

clase Author.cpp

```
 Author::Author(const string & name, const string & email, char gender) : name(name) {
     setEmail(email);  // Call setter to check for valid email
     if (gender == 'm' || gender == 'f') {
        this->gender = gender;
     } else {
     cout << "Invalid gender! Set to 'u' (unknown)." << endl;
     this->gender = 'u';
    }
}
void Author::setEmail(const string & email) {
   // Check for valid email. Assume that a valid email contains
   //  a '@' that is not the first nor last character.
   size_t atIndex = email.find('@');
   if (atIndex != string::npos && atIndex != 0 && atIndex !=  email.length()-1) {
        this->email = email;
   } else {
        cout << "Invalid email! Set to empty string." << endl;
        this->email = "";
   }
}
```

saludos,
JC.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo estás haciendo de la forma correcta; tu problema está en el constructor de `Author`. Deberías de mostrar esa clase; o, al menos, las variables-miembro y el constructor. Y si colocaras un [mcve], mucho mejor :-)

Comment: constructor de author.                                           '       Author::Author(const string & name, const string & email, char gender) : name(name) {
         setEmail(email);  // Call setter to check for valid email
        if (gender == 'm' || gender == 'f') {
        this->gender = gender;
        } else {
        cout << "Invalid gender! Set to 'u' (unknown)." << endl;
        this->gender = 'u';
        }
}

Comment: A ver. La 2ª cosa que intentaste, no te va a funcionar nunca. La 1ª, debería. Salvo que `Author::name` sea una referencia, en cuyo caso tampoco. Por favor, muestra el código; jugar a *adivinar* es perder el tiempo de todos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta... si esperas que la gente se lea código en los comentarios vas a perder el interés de la gente

Comment: En la edición, ya esta el constructor y el método que usa en su interior. como puedes comprobar.